# Вывод статей из базы данных

Tags: php, база-данных

У меня есть код добавления данных в базу и вывод на главную.

Идея в том, чтобы статьи выводились на главной все, а по ссылке :

https://example.ru/article.php/1
Только статья с id = 1.

Код на странице article.php :

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC"; // сортировка по id по возрастанию
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query); // отправка запроса к БД и получение ответа
 if($result){
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк
        }

            for ($i = $rows ; $i > 0 ; --$i){ // цикл вывода статей
                $count += 1; // сразу прибавляем счетчик
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); // получаем текущий row
                echo '<a class="stat" id="n1" href="https://c-sports.ru/article.php/'. $i .'" align="center"><img src = "'.$row[4].'" class="imagestat"><h3 class="zag">' . $row[1] . '</h3><br>'; // выводим блок с заголовком статьи
                echo '<p class="tx">'.$row[3].'</p></a>'."\r\n"; // выводим описание к статье
?>
```

Мне нужно всего лишь выводить данные статьи в единичном экземпляре, а не все статьи, как на главной.
Прошу помощи, не знаю что нужно написать, может, какое-то условие.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $myID ORDER BY id DESC". Вам стоит сделать уточнение что именно вы ищете

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 1;
"SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Comment: А зачем делать `ORDER BY id DESC` если ожидается одна запись?

Comment: Согласен, не за чем. Просто скопировал строку автора )

Answer (score 0):

Провернуть выборку по заданному урлу `https://example.ru/article.php/1`
не получится, ибо уже нужно пилить роутинг. Провернуть можно через `GET` запрос и урл уже будет выглядеть след. образом `https://example.ru/article.php?id=1`

Тогда, по такой уже ссылке, будет доступна переменная $_GET['id'] и уже с ней пилим выборку, проверяем как и что должно выводиться.